# Отправить 5 запросов через Retrofit 2 с разными id и получить товары

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Есть 5 id в `idList`. Эти id мне надо добавить в запросы к запросам через retrofit. Каждый такой запрос должен мне отдать уникальный Product.

В итоге я хочу получить 5 Product'ов в том же порядке, что и id в `idList`, их добавить в products и отправить их в адаптер.

Вот такое чудо я накодил, но ошибку пишет на строке `loadData()` внутри loadData(). Как я понял вызывать заново метод loadData внутри этого же метода не самое правильное решение.

Подскажите как правильно сделать.

```
ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList(); //5 id товаров
currentProductId = 0; // счетчик товаров, когда счетчик будет больше чем товаров в idList, 
//тогда добавлять товары в адаптер и выводить их.
List<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();

private void loadData() {
    запрос, currentProductId.enqueue {
        if (idList != currentProductId) {
            products.add(response.body());
            currentProductId++;
            loadData(); //тут ошибка, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        }
        if (idList == currentProductId) {
            adapter.setItems(products);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант с rxjava

Comment: Сорри но сейчас мой мозг не осилит еще и понимание rxjava, надо пока стандартными средствами, а как с ними застабилюсь, тогда и новые штуки учить буду

Comment: А Ваш сервер не принимает несколько id одним запросом - это было бы проще и лучше, даже если порядок не гарантирован (отсортировать пара пустяков). Вы привели такой код, по которому сложно понять где именно Ваша ошибка, понятно одно - что неправильно проверяется окончание списка, нужно поставить эту проверку сразу при входе в метод, наверное. Не уверен, конечно, но имя метода `enqueue` намекает на то, что запросы обрабатываются по очереди, можно попробовать просто в цикле их запустить, а в адаптер можно добавлять и по одному.

Comment: в этом и проблема что сервер только по очереди отдает товары, по одному товару на запрос. Можно сделать так:
for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
loadData(i);
}
Но тогда очередность товаров теряется ибо запросы выполняются хаотично.

Comment: Есть у ретрофита синхронный запрос https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#execute-- , но тогда цикл придётся самому заворачивать в фоновый поток.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если попытаться исправить Ваш код, то должно быть как-то так:

```
ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList(); //5 id товаров
currentProductId = 0; // счетчик товаров, когда счетчик будет больше чем товаров в idList, 
//тогда добавлять товары в адаптер и выводить их.
List<Products> products = new ArrayList<>();

private void loadData() {
    if (currentProductId >= idList.size()) {
        adapter.setItems(products);
        return;
    }
    //запрос, currentProductId.enqueue, onResponse {
         products.add(response.body());
         currentProductId++;
         loadData();
    //
}
```

Comment: Код работает и в моем случае товары выдает именно по очереди (использую .enqueue запрос). Классно что мой ум сдвинулся и вы мне показали что можно делать проверку внутри метода перед выполнением запроса, огромное вам спасибо. Неделю потратил на этот кусок кода, но решил задачу, еее

Comment: @SergeyValue, если ответ помог решить вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный (галочка рядом с ответом)